# Seeking a Tool to Monitor Stack Exchange Posts for Relevant Discussions

Tags: web-apps, machine-learning, nlp, social-networks

I've developed a tool for Reddit that uses natural language processing and machine learning to keep track of posts that discuss a problem my product can solve. It's been incredibly useful, or so I thought, until I realized that there are no such posts on Reddit. I mean, who has problems on Reddit? It's all memes, cats, and karma. So I've decided to look elsewhere for potential customers, and Stack Exchange seems like a promising place.

Before I dive in, I wanted to check in with this knowledgeable community: Is there an existing tool that monitors Stack Exchange in a way similar to my Reddit tool? If so, it would be great if you could point me towards it, so I can save myself some time and effort.

Here's a brief overview of what my Reddit tool does:

1. I mark a Reddit post as an example of a problem my product can solve.
2. The tool then monitors new posts, scoring them based on their similarity to the examples I've provided.
3. When it finds a match (i.e., a post that scores above a certain threshold), it notifies me so I can engage with the post.
   Or rather, it would notify me, if it ever found a match. Which it hasn't. Ever.

I'm looking for a tool that can do something similar with Stack Exchange posts. Preferably one that actually works.